# Finding limits with algebraic analysis without derivatives

Tags: limits

My tutor has given me an assignment to find limit of 
$$\tan(\pi\cdot x)\cdot \ln(1+x)$$ when 'x' tends to $-1$ from right hand side without any use of calculus. I understand, that tan term tends to zero and ln term tends to -infinity but I dont how we may compare them and where at , zero or at infinity?

Comment: How has your tutor defined $\ln$ without calculus?

Comment: @JohnHughes It's not about *defining* $\ln$, It's about finding limit without L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Yeah , @JaideepKhare , you are right.

Comment: For me, limit itself is a part of calculus. What is probably desired here is a solution which does not use any derivatives/integrals or power series techniques and instead relies on usual algebra of limits. Also the comment from @JohnHughes raises a subtle point about definition of logarithm which many cheap calculus textbooks avoid.

Comment: @JaideepKhare: My preferred definition of $\ln$ is that $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} ~ dt$. It's very hard to prove anything about that without using integrals. Your definition may be "log is the inverse function of $\exp$", which requires a proof that $\exp$ exists and has the properties necessary for its inverse to exist...and when you try to establish this, suddenly my preferred definition looks a lot better, and you're back to the problem of talking about an integral without using integrals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x=-1+h$, where $h \to 0$.

Your expression reduces to $$M=\lim_{h \to 0}\tan(-\pi+h \pi) \cdot \ln(h)=\lim_{h \to 0}\tan (h \pi)\ln(h)=\underbrace{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\tan (h \pi)}{h \pi}}_{=1} \cdot \pi \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} h\ln(h)$$

Thus, all you need to find is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+}x\ln(x)$.

Let $x=e^{-t}$ and note that as $x \to 0^+$, we have $t \to \infty$. Hence,
$$L = \lim_{x \to 0} x \ln(x) = \lim_{t \to \infty} -te^{-t} = -\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{t}{e^t}$$
Now recall that $e^t \geq \dfrac{t^2}2$. Hence, we have
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{t}{e^t} \leq \lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac2t = 0$$
This gives us $M=\pi L=0$.

Comment: I must say, a very good answer.